# Trying to get property of non-object error when using json

Tags: php, angularjs, xampp

I keep getting the following error

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **D:\XAMPP\htdocs\website\php\login.php** on line **4**

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **D:\XAMPP\htdocs\website\php\login.php** on line **5**

I am using AngularJS to get the input from a form, sending the data to a php using console.log function and decoding the json file using php, then checking a database to find info matching the input values.

JS:

```
$scope.login = function(acc) {
    console.log(acc);//getting data input by user

    //post is used to create
    $http.post('php/login.php', {'user': $scope.acc.user, 'pass': $scope.acc.pass}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {//row inserted
          // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
          console.log("Succesful");
          $scope.insertMessage = "Data inserted";
        } else {
          // if unsuccessful, bind success message to message
          $scope.insertMessage = "Data not inserted";
        }
        $scope.acc="";//reset values in form to empty
        //redirect to list
    });

    $http.get('php/login.php').success(function(logged){
            $scope.loggedin = logged;
            console.log($scope.loggedin);
      })
      .error(function(err){
          $log.error(err);
      });   
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$user = $data->user;
$pass = $data->pass;

require_once("connection.php");

$conn = connectToDb();
$query= "SELECT count(*) 
FROM tbl_logdetails 
WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) 
    or die("error in query: ".mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];

echo $count;

if($count == 0){
    $logged = false;
}else{
    $logged=true;
}
echo json_encode($logged);

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: var_dump the result of `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`, what do you get? This is where your problem is.

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(5) "admin"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}

Comment: If that's the output, what you have should work, you put that `var_dump` in the exact code that wasn't working and ran it?

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau Yep, this is what the console looks like: https://gyazo.com/0a38ca0d2dec8996b74d869764298808. I just noticed it looks like the login function might be running twice, can't make sense of why this is happening though.

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau up until the "Successful" notification everything looks to be working as it should.

Comment: Wait aren't you calling login with POST and then login with GET right after each other? And you're not passing anything to the GET login thing, hence the non-object. So your script is working but adding those extra errors?

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau yeah that was it... can't believe i didn't catch that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Since I'm greedy for rep, I'm going to add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you calling login with POST and then login with GET right after each other? And you're not passing anything to the GET login attempt, hence the non-object when you use `json_decode`. So your script is working on the POST attempt but printing out the error messages on the GET attempt.

Remove this part:

```
$http.get('php/login.php').success(function(logged){
            $scope.loggedin = logged;
            console.log($scope.loggedin);
      })
      .error(function(err){
          $log.error(err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The $http.get was redundant and was executing login.php again without giving any parameters, removing the $http.get was the solution...

```
$scope.login = function(acc) {
    console.log(acc);//getting data input by user

    //post is used to create
    $http.post('php/login.php', {'user': $scope.acc.user, 'pass': $scope.acc.pass}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {//row inserted
          // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
          console.log("Succesful");
          $scope.insertMessage = "Data inserted";
          $scope.loggedin = data;
            console.log($scope.loggedin);
        } else {
          // if unsuccessful, bind success message to message
          $scope.insertMessage = "Data not inserted";
        }
        $scope.acc="";//reset values in form to empty
        //redirect to list

    });
};
```